# second parameter for filter method in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I use following code to search a tableviewcontroller in my app.
Currently search string matches with  restaurant name in my table list. I wish to match/search additional string , location with my code. How can I add location to this function

restaurant name variable - restaurant.name ,
restaurant location variable - restaurant.location

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        searchResults = restaurants.filter({ ( restaurant: Restaurant) -> Bool in let nameMatch = restaurant.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
        NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return nameMatch != nil
        })
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

How can I add this additional parameter in my filter method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        searchResults = restaurants.filter({ ( restaurant: Restaurant) -> Bool in 

        let nameMatch = restaurant.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
        NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)

        let locationMatch = restaurant.location.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
        NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)

        return (nameMatch != nil || locationMatch != nil)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can do like this

```
 func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

        searchResults = restaurants.filter({( restaurant: Restaurant) -> Bool in

          return restaurant.location.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) || restaurant.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)

        })

        tableView.reloadData()
      }
```

> Delegate Method

```
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
  }
```

This method will help you search in better way